# Set running time limit on a method in java

Tags: java, string

I have a method that returns a String.

Is it possible that after a certain time, if threshold is excedeed for that method, to return some specific string?

Comment: Waht you want is to call your method and if its execution time exceeds a certain amount the returning String is a constant?

Comment: @reef nop, when method x which returns some String reaches i.e. 6 seconds running time that it returns some error string .. or just have some kind of callback which I can use to handle the time error.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava) has a very nice [`TimeLimiter`](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/util/concurrent/TimeLimiter.java) that lets you do this on any method that's defined by an interface. It can generate a proxy for your object that has a "built-in" timeout.

Comment: this seems it, just let me ask you this, this example is not clear for me because I'm a noob, `to return the value of target.someMethod()` , does this `target` refer to class instance?

Comment: another question, what if this method is opening some sessions, will they be closed? Or I need to put this close sessions before returning default value?

Comment: @London.  1) yes that's what it means.  2) the method needs to close those sessions using a `try {...} finally {...}`.  But it should be doing that anyway!!!

Comment: The caller will timeout and return the string but the actual runnable may still be running and continue running.

Answer (score 12):

I did something similar in the past when spawning an external process with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command)`. I think you could do something like this within your method:

```java
Timer timer = new Timer(true);
InterruptTimerTask interruptTimerTask = new InterruptTimerTask(Thread.currentThread());
timer.schedule(interruptTimerTask, waitTimeout);
try {
    // put here the portion of code that may take more than "waitTimeout"
}
catch (InterruptedException e) {
    log.error("timeout exeeded");
}
finally {
    timer.cancel();
}
```

and here is `InterruptTimerTask`

```java
/*
 * A TimerTask that interrupts the specified thread when run.
 */
protected class InterruptTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    private Thread theTread;
    
    public InterruptTimerTask(Thread theTread) {
        this.theTread = theTread;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        theTread.interrupt();
    }
}
```

Comment: "Scedule" isn't used as a time limit, but as a delay... so "waitTimeout" in this case is the delay before interruptTimerTask is executed... from the API: Schedules the specified task for execution after the specified delay.

Comment: I get an error in the try/catch: `Unreachable catch block for InterruptedException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body.`

Answer (score 2):

As answered of @MarcoS

I found timeout is not  raised if method is locking something and not release cpu time to Timer.
Then Timer cannot start new thread.
So I change a bit by start Thread immediately and sleep inside thread.

```
        InterruptTimerTaskAddDel interruptTimerTask = new InterruptTimerTaskAddDel(
                Thread.currentThread(),timeout_msec);

        timer.schedule(interruptTimerTask, 0);

        /*
 * A TimerTask that interrupts the specified thread when run.
 */
class InterruptTimerTaskAddDel extends TimerTask {

    private Thread theTread;
    private long timeout;

    public InterruptTimerTaskAddDel(Thread theTread,long i_timeout) {
        this.theTread = theTread;
        timeout=i_timeout;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.currentThread().sleep(timeout);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
        }
        theTread.interrupt();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use AOP and a [`@Timeable`](http://aspects.jcabi.com/apidocs-0.7.16/com/jcabi/aspects/Timeable.html) annotation from [jcabi-aspects](http://aspects.jcabi.com/annotation-timeable.html) (I'm a developer):

```
@Timeable(limit = 1, unit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
String load(String resource) {
  while (true) {
    if (Thread.currentThread.isInterrupted()) {
      throw new IllegalStateException("time out");
    }
    // execution as usual
  }
}
```

When time limit is reached your thread will get `interrupted()` flag set to `true` and it's your job to handle this situation correctly and to stop execution.

Also, check this blog post: http://www.yegor256.com/2014/06/20/limit-method-execution-time.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using Guava `SimpleTimeLimiter`

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter;
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.TimeLimiter;

import java.time.Duration;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException;

class TimeoutExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, TimeoutException, ExecutionException {
        TimeLimiter timeLimiter = SimpleTimeLimiter.create(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
        Duration timeout = Duration.ofMillis(500);

        String result = timeLimiter.callWithTimeout(() -> possiblyLongMethod(100), timeout); // will return
        System.out.println(result);
        String result2 = timeLimiter.callWithTimeout(() -> possiblyLongMethod(1000), timeout); // will timeout
        System.out.println(result2);

    }

    public static String possiblyLongMethod(int runtime) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread.sleep(runtime);
        return "Ran for " + runtime + "ms";
    }
}
```

The first call will return sucessfully as the call only takes 100ms, but the second will fail with a `TimeoutException` as it would take 1000ms