# How to run a method for a particular duration of time?

Tags: java, multithreading

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243233/set-running-time-limit-on-a-method-in-java/5243339#5243339)

How do you know if the method successfully completed or if it was interrupted?

**Edit**: To make the question more clear and specific.Below is my code .. I want to execute the test.java file for and get its runtime.. However if it takes more than 1 sec I want to display an error message and stop it there itself ..

```
public class cl {  
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException  
    {  
        String s=null;  
    Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac C:\\Users\\Lokesh\\Desktop\\test.java");  
    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));  
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {  
            System.out.println(s);  
    }  
    Timer timer=new Timer(true);  
    InterruptTimerTask interruptTimerTask=new InterruptTimerTask(Thread.currentThread());  
    timer.schedule(interruptTimerTask,1);  
    try{  
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java C:\\Users\\Lokesh\\Desktop\\test");  
    }  
    catch (Exception e)  
    {  
        e.printStackTrace();  
    }  
    finally {  
        timer.cancel();  
    }  
}  
static class InterruptTimerTask extends TimerTask {  
    private Thread thread;  
    public InterruptTimerTask(Thread thread)  
    {  
        this.thread=thread;  
    }  
    @Override  
    public void run()  
    {  
        thread.interrupt();  
    }  
}  
}
```

Comment: Define "interrupted".  Did you return early/fail-fast?  Was there an exception thrown?  Did the machine put that thread of execution to sleep and not get back to it?

Comment: isnt that what try catch blocks are for??

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to understand what terminated your thread is to have a boolean flag, call it 'interrupted', and set it when you catch the `InterruptedException`. Assuming that your code doesn't do anything else that can throw that exception, you can check the value of the flag in the code that follows.

Answer (score 0):

As the exapmle:

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(10000);
    // method successfully completed

} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    // method was interrupted. You can try sleep some more time if you want
}
```

`Thread.sleep()` is one of methods that can be interrupted. There can be any another method instead, or even your's method if it checks it's interrupted state. If your method realized that someone wants to interrupt it, it must throw `InterruptedException` (not must, sometimes it will be better to continue running).

**[The Interrupt Status Flag](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html)**

*The interrupt mechanism is implemented using an internal flag known as the interrupt status. Invoking Thread.interrupt sets this flag. When a thread checks for an interrupt by invoking the static method Thread.interrupted, interrupt status is cleared. The non-static isInterrupted method, which is used by one thread to query the interrupt status of another, does not change the interrupt status flag.*

*By convention, any method that exits by throwing an InterruptedException clears interrupt status when it does so. However, it's always possible that interrupt status will immediately be set again, by another thread invoking interrupt.*