# Cannot get Guava 23's SimpleTimeLimiter example to compile

Tags: java, guava

I'm following a combination of code that I see many times online, [including examples here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5243249/39371), etc. but it just won't compile for me.

```
import com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class TimeLimit
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SimpleTimeLimiter limiter = new SimpleTimeLimiter();
        String result = limiter.callWithTimeout(new Callable<String>()
        {
            public String call()
            {
                return longTimeExecutingMethod();
            }
        }, 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS, false);
    }

    public static String longTimeExecutingMethod()
    {
        return "long time executing method";
    }
}
```

The errors I'm getting are:

```
Error:(10, 45) java: constructor SimpleTimeLimiter in class com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

And:

```
Error:(11, 40) java: method callWithTimeout in class com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.util.concurrent.Callable<T>,long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
  found: <anonymous java.util.concurrent.Callable<java.lang.String>>,int,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit,boolean
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

For the first Error I tried to create a Single Thread Executor:

```
SimpleTimeLimiter limiter = new SimpleTimeLimiter(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor());
```

But that only resulted in changing the first compiler error with:

```
Error:(10, 45) java: SimpleTimeLimiter(java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService) has private access in com.google.common.util.concurrent.SimpleTimeLimiter
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [static factory method](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/SimpleTimeLimiter.html#create-java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService-):

```
SimpleTimeLimiter limiter = SimpleTimeLimiter.create(executor);
```

Comment: That solves the first issue. Any idea for the second compilation error?

Comment: "actual and formal argument lists differ in length" You're passing an extra parameter (the boolean).